# How to change my W2k8 System Partition?

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition

On my Windows 2008 server, my C: is 1.5 TB, and the partition is marked as:  Healthy (Boot, Page File, Active, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)

and somehow I ended up with a 2GB D: that is marked as Healthy (System).

On this D: drive are only a few MB worth of files (bootmgr, boot folder, bootsect.bak), but all Windows files are on the c:.

I've done everything I can to remove the (System) mark.  I tried using bcdedit, I tried marking the C:partition as "Active", I tried using bootsect.exe to assign the C: drive as the boot partition.  Maybe I didn't do one of those steps correct, but I've tried everything I can.

When I got my new Dell Poweredge T710, I didn't bother removing their 2 small drives before I put in my 2 new large drives.  So I think when I installed W2k8 Server, maybe dell left some bootable partition on their drives to help me install the OS, but I never used it and just booted right from the install CD.

Can anyone help me remove the (System) mark from the D: so I can remove the D: partition and still boot to the C:?

I know I could remove the D: drives and reinstall windows, but I'm trying to avoid a total reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Is the partition marked **System Reserved**? If so, this is required by the OS and shouldn't be deleted. However, it also shouldn't have a drive letter assigned, and should only be 100Mb. Has the server been built fully with apps etc, or is this still just a base OS install with no configuration?

Outside of that, then it does sound like Dell cruft. In which case you may be able to remove the partition using a liveCD such as [gParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

However before you do this, I would ensure you're in a position to effectively lose the whole OS install. gParted works most of the time, but not 100%, and I can't give you a guarantee that this mystery partition is completely safe to delete.

Comment: I don't think it's marked as "System Reserved."  In Disk Manager it just says "Healthy (System)".

If I remove the D: drives from the machine, it doesn't boot. So I'm guessing that gParted won't help there.  I don't really need to delete the D: partition so much as I just want to get rid of the drives that D: is on, but I can't because then the computer doesn't boot.

Lately I've been trying all kinds of repair options, but at this point I keep getting "BOOTMGR is missing".

Comment: It looks like I found a solution!

Doing all the bootrec /rebuildbcd /fixmbr /fixboot didn't get me across the finish line, but the bcdedit and bootrec /rebuildbcd got me to the point where I was getting the BOOTMGR is missing error.  After that, based on some suggestions I tried using a Vista x64 CD and used the repair option from that.  In  the Vista repair options, unlike in 2008, it gives you a Startup Repair link you can click.  It worked!